# How to embed live stock quotes in a modern SharePoint 2019 site?

Tags: iframe, sharepoint

I am trying to find a way, to implement live stock information (e.g. stock ticker / charts) in a SharePoint 2019 site.

I already tried to find iframes in order to embed the information on the site. But unfortunately I couldn't find any.

There are several "widgets" which support real time stock information as ticker or chart but unfortunately it is not possible to embed these widgets in SharePoint 2019.

Anyone an idea or workaround to implement the stock information to SharePoint 2019?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good stock ticker plugin for you which is supported.

BTW , I am the author, and can help you customize it as well

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104381291

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We gonna check it out!